# How to use one ViewModel for all CRUD operations in WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am making a little API in asp.net. It is coupled with an MVC webapp. I intend for the webapp to use it's own API instead of creating 2 backends that do the same thing.

I am struggling a little to try and keep my duplicate code to a minimum when it comes to creating a model to use in the API for both "incoming" (Post, Put) and "outgoing" (get) actions.

I have a class called `Event`, it contains properties that are easy to serialize to JSON plus a few complex types. I created a model called `EventViewModel` (is it appropriate to still call it a *view* model in API?) with some extra properties to get the `Name`s out of the complex types.

Ideally, I'd like to re-use this Model for everything, but when it comes to defining`[Required]` tags, my logic breaks down...

I first thought of using `[Bind(Include() Exclude()]` on each of the API actions. Does this sound like a viable solution?

What other solutions have people used?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here are some thoughts.

I would use separate controllers for view (Controller) and api (ApiController) since we are talking about two different presentations of data. I would not use the controller as an api, since both return different types. An api controller uses statuscodes in a different way. E.g. ApiController.Delete returns statuscode 204 No Content, while Controller returns statuscode 200 Ok with a view.

You can call the models for Controller ViewModels and for ApiController DTO's. In either case, they are just simple objects. Don't put any logic in those objects except for validation (which you can test with the ModelState) and don't use entity objects.

Do not use models / dto's for multiple purposes for the reason you've already encountered. Just use simple objects and use those only once, keep it simple. In that case, if you want to change something you know it is not going to break your application.

You can save code by using base classes that you can inherit. This will also give you the advantage of writing extensions once for different objects.

But if you insist in reusing objects, you can decide not to use ModelState.Validate in Api's. I think in that case the [required] tag is ignored, but I am not sure. As for the objects, I would not use JsonIgnore / Xmlignore but set default values instead. In that case these properties are omitted on serialization. Makes it easy to use objects for both POST and GET.

```
    [DefaultValue(0)]
    public int Id { get; set; } = 0;
```

Use repositories. You can call the repositories in both the controller as in the api controller. This is where you can really save code.

For Api's (not CRUD) I prefer to write specialized linq queries that return anonymous objects and select those into the dto. This gives multiple advantages. Sometimes I use extensions (on IQueryable) to save code.

You may want to consider using something like automapper to save code, but I wouldn't recommend this.

Comment: Not what I wanted to hear, but a good answer regardless. I figured I may have to make multiple models/controllers for the different services. Thank you. I am using Automapper. I am curious as to why you wouldn't recommend it. I am having a great time with it so far.

Comment: Well actually I've never used automapper, but it seems to me that it is adding complexity to an application.